# react-router: URL parameters exist in two different places in this.props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router, url-routing

```
<Route path="lookbook" component={Photos} onEnter={onPageEnter}>
  <Route path=":photoIdentifier" component={PhotoDetailsModal} onEnter={onPageEnter}>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

So if I am in `PhotoDetailsModal` and `console.log` `this.props`. I notice that my `:photoIdentifier` parameter exists in two different spots. In `this.props.params.photoIdentifier` and as `this.props.routeParams.photoIdentifier`. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`routeParams` is a subset of `this.props.params` that were directly specified in this component's route.

For example, if the route's path is `lookbook/:photoIdentifier` and the URL is `/lookkook/123/photoId/345` then this.props.routeParams will be `{photoIdentifier: '123'}`, and `this.props.params` will be `{photoIdentifier: '123', photoId: 345}`.

I suppose this answers yours question